confused about how the dynamic memory allocation works in assembly (brk)
According to my understanding, the brk syscall allows you to set the memory available to the process, and I assume that the process cannot access any memory after the break point.
Well, the code below is confusing me:
.global _start
.intel_syntax noprefix 

.section .bss
.lcomm init_brk_loc, 8
.lcomm brk_loc, 8

.section .data

.section .text
_start:
    #get initial break size
    mov rax, 12
    mov rdi, 0 #to get the break location
    syscall
    mov qword ptr [init_brk_loc], rax
    mov qword ptr [brk_loc], rax

    #allocate more memory
    mov rax, 12
    mov rdi, [init_brk_loc]
    add rdi, 2
    syscall
    mov qword ptr [brk_loc], rax

    #insert data 
    mov rax, [init_brk_loc]
    mov byte ptr [rax], 'a'
    mov byte ptr [rax + 1], 'b'
    mov byte ptr [rax + 2], 'c'
    mov byte ptr [rax + 3], '\n'

    #write
    mov rdx, 4
    mov rsi, [init_brk_loc]
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rax, 1
    syscall

    #free the memory
    mov rax, 12
    mov rdi, [init_brk_loc]
    syscall

    #exit
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall

if my assumption is correct (which doesn't seem to be), then I shouldn't be able to insert data after brk_loc, and worse, to be able to write it.
so, I'd like to understand what's happening, and why it's happening.
thanks to everyone <3

Memory protection has page (i.e. 4 kB) granularity.  The limits given by the brk system call apply in 4 kB increments only.

The operating system basically cannot give you less than a page, but it does remember how much you did actually asked for, so you do not have to know about page size for any reason of the programming model, unless you're deliberately trying to cause an exception / segfault.  Rather than merely rounding up to give you a whole page, it pretends it gave only what was asked for, so another request will start at the appropriate location rather than a page boundary.

partial duplicate: Why when I reserve less memory in assembly .bss section it doesn't segfault until I reserve 0? - covers the fact that memory protection works with page granularity, but not the part @ErikEidt mentioned about how the break is still tracked with byte granularity for the kernel to decide when it needs to map a new page.
